# Scale zedGraph to fit paper size

Tags: c#, vb.net, zedgraph

I have created an application and managed to draw the graph with zedGraph  as I would like it but when I use the print command it’s not scaled to fit the paper size which I have selected.  It looks as if it just try’s to print what I have on the screen.  Can anyone tell me how I can get zedGrapg to resize to fix the selected paper size correctly.

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out to set the print margins:

```
    Dim marg As New System.Drawing.Printing.Margins
    marg.Left = 10
    marg.Right = 10
    marg.Top = 10
    marg.Bottom = 10

    zg1.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = marg
```

Hope this help.